# What are phrases with these forms called?: being + adjective; preposition + being + adjective

Tags: grammar, syntax, parts-of-speech

For example:

- I apologized for *being rude* to Paul.
- *Being kind* is a virtue.
- His *being dishonest* did not help him socially.

These phrases are clearly functioning as nouns but the participle (being) seems to be functioning more like a verb than a noun. Are these noun phrases or verb phrases functioning as nouns? And how should *being* be classified as word (PoS)? Is it a participle, a verb or a gerund? This is really just a question about syntax, I understand what these phrases mean. I'm more interested in the terms of analysis.

Comment: No, they are not nouns, they are all gerund-participial clauses with "being" as the verb, and the adjectives "rude/kind/dishonest" as predicative complements of "being". "Being rude ..." functions as complement of "for"; "being kind" functions as subject; "being dishonest" is the predicate verb phrase of the clause "his being dishonest", which functions as subject.

Comment: Although not wrong, I think the last example is awkward. I'd avoid it.  Better to say "His dishonesty did not help him socially".

Comment: @BillyKerr I agree it's awkward, but for some reason, I think it's somewhat more dynamic than *his dishonesty*: it describes his behavior rather than his character. What say you?

Comment: @user178049 - I'm honestly not sure about your suggestion - I supposed that could be argued. But it's awkwardness alone is enough for me want to change the wording.  If I wanted to specifically mention his behaviour, then I'd probably say "His dishonest behaviour ...". Perhaps my perception of awkwardness here is because I'm British. Perhaps Americans find this more acceptable.

Comment: I didn't say they were nouns. One is the object of a preposition, two are subjects and here's one as an object - 'Try being kind.' These roles are usually taken by nouns, hence they function like nouns, in the position of subject, verb complement and landmark of a preposition, or complement as is preferred by some. I thought of seeing them as clauses, as a version of - It did not help him that he was dishonest. I think that seeing these as clauses is the best answer.

Comment: A phrase or clause cannot function as a noun. Functions are subject, object, complement etc. Noun, verb adjective etc. are word categories (parts of speech). You cannot conflate the two concepts by saying that some phrase or clause is functioning as a noun; that is your mistake. In your first example "being rude to Paul" is a gerund-participial clause, and its function is that of complement of the preposition "for".

Comment: Grammar is Babylon.

Comment: What? If you can't distinguish form and function of clause constituents, you will never be able to understand English syntax.

Comment: Understanding English syntax is very much complicated by the sheer volume of theories and terminologies in the fields of grammar and linguistics. A problem that you appear to have resolved by latching on to CGEL. As John Lawler has stated: "No one, of course, is obliged to use any grammatical term (or for that matter any other kind of term) the same way as anyone else.  However, if one insists that a term must mean exactly what they expect it to mean, they may often be disappointed in others' practice."

Comment: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html

Comment: @UbuEnglish I honestly have no idea what you're trying to say here. The only one who argues about terminology is you; nobody else does. You can call it whatever you want: *gerund participle* or just *gerund* (as Carnie does in his *Generative Syntax*). The essential point is just that **the distinction between gerund and present participle cannot be sustained** as Huddlestion and Pullum said in CGEL (p. 82).

Answer (score 1):

"These phrases are clearly functioning as nouns but the participle (being) seems to be functioning more like a verb than a noun"—nouns and verbs aren't grammatical functions; they're word classes (or parts of speech). So it doesn't make sense to say a word functions as a noun or as a verb.

"Is it a participle, a verb or a gerund?"—this doesn't really make sense either. Gerunds and participles are verb forms. You shouldn't mix them with word classes in the same category.

They're all gerund-participial clauses*: *Being rude to Paul* functions as the complement of the preposition *for*; *His being dishonest* and *being rude* both function as subjects.

---

<sup>*We no longer distinguish between a gerund and a present participle. Some grammarians shove them together into a single compound term *gerund-participle*.</sup>

Comment: Yes. Small point: in the OP's example, the gerund-participial in full is "being rude to Paul" where the PP "to Paul" is complement of "rude".

Comment: Word classes absolutely represent grammatical functions, words alone do not. A word doesn't have a class or function until it is used in a phrase of some kind. Gerunds are participles that sometimes function like a noun - I like swimming - a verbal noun, and sometimes more like verbs - I like swimming in the ocean - more like a verb. The term gerund participle makes no sense to me. A gerund is a participle. The terms participle noun, participle verb, and participle adjective would make more sense. Where did you get that statement "We no longer..." from? Also there's an adjective in there.

Comment: @UbuEnglish There's nothing wrong with user 178049's answer; it accords perfectly with modern grammar which does not distinguish gerund and present participle simply because there's no need to, which is why the _ing_ forms are called gerund-participles, and the clauses they head are called gerund-participial clauses. The two most influential grammars of the last 50 years, CaCGEL (Quirk at al) and CGEL (Huddleston &Pullum) are in agreement on the point that _ing_ words are a single item in the verb paradigm, hence the term ‘gerund-participle’. You really need to keep up with modern grammar.

Comment: I think you're overestimating CGEL's impact and prevalence in modern grammar, which in my experience has no real standards, and is pretty much a mixed bag. What I wanted was some insight into the linguistic feature I'm asking about, not an argument about terminology.

Comment: @UbuEnglish If you're aware of GGEL's grammar, why did you ask user178049 where they got the term 'gerund-participle' from? And in any case your question was answered perfectly by user178049. They answered your question satisfactorily. Read your question again and you'll see that you asked about analysis, and that means identifying categories and functions.

Comment: And what you say about CGEL (if indeed you really have looked at it) is nonsense. By any standards it's a ground-breaking grammar, written by a team of the world's finest linguists, and the winner of the Leonard Bloomfield book award from the Linguistic Society of America 2004. Revered around the world as probably the finest grammar ever written. And you dismiss it as 'having no real standards' and 'a mixed bag'.  You don't know much about English grammar, do you?

Comment: What I said is 'modern grammar' is a mixed bag and lacking in standards, not CGEL (the syntax is clear). I'm also saying that CGEL is not the defacto standard, however good or well received it may be. For example, a Google search for 'gerund-participle' returns very few results related to CGEL or the term. Rather it returns results where you will find grammatical distinctions between a gerund and a participle. I'm not dismissing CGEL, I'm just saying that it is has not standardized English grammar, much as such a thing would improve the overall situation for learners. So much noise out there.

Comment: Furthermore, please see pg 81 (The traditional gerund) in CGEL, which uses language similar that in my post.

Comment: @UbuEnglish You still haven't understood the main point here. Please reread my answer. And seeing as you have a copy of CGEL, I think you should read the *Preliminary* part. You'll see how important it is to distinguish grammatical functions (subject, predicator, complement etc.) from parts of speech (verb, noun, preposition etc.)